# Which component is sorting JSON values in Rails JSON response and why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I noticed Rails JSON output is alphabetically sorted.

This is a sample JSON output from a basic Rails app:

```
{"created_at":"2013-02-03T19:44:39Z","email":"mohsen@example.com","id":2,"name":"Mohsen","updated_at":"2013-02-03T19:44:39Z"}
```

It seems `created_at` and `updated_at` have same origin and probably should come next to each other. But Rails output is alphabetically sorted.

Which component is doing this work and why?

Comment: Is it because of `OrderedHash` or because you're using ruby < 1.9? I'm not sure what's going on but here's the source for the Rails json encoding. https://github.com/mateusg/docrails_pt-BR/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb

Comment: Are you using ruby 1.9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that the first line of `ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON#as_json` calls `ActiveModel::Serialization#serializable_hash`, which has [this line of code that sorts the attribute names](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3508da50f02b11290245976f2dbaeef6cd794e83/activemodel/lib/active_model/serialization.rb#L71):

```
attribute_names = attributes.keys.sort
```

This is where the attributes are sorted. As for *why* they are sorted, the answer is less clear. [Josh Peek introduced the sort in this commit way back in July of 2009](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/783db25e0c640c1588732967a87d65c10fddc08e), but the commit comment was simply "Integrate AMo JSON serializer into AR." He didn't say why he added the call to `.sort`.

But if you don't like the sort, you're in luck as long as you're willing to upgrade to Rails 4 when it comes out. The Rails core team seems to agree that the JSON keys shouldn't be sorted. [In March of 2012 they accepted this pull request in which the call to `sort` was removed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cf833b9d97f612ed2105ca4c467f03f812433320). This commit is not in the latest Rails 3.2 but will be in Rails 4, which is coming soon.