# How to sort Rails Active Model serializers' response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

Weirdly, I haven't find anything on the subject...

How can I sort the JSON my Rails server delivers? I am currently using ActiveModel Serializer :

```
 embed :ids, include: true
 attributes :id, :name

 has_many :places
```

I would like to sort the embedded `places`.

The only answer I found is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676943/which-component-is-sorting-json-values-in-rails-json-response-and-why), but it explains how the serializer sort by default, instead of how I can sort.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can define it as property and handle sorting. E.g:

```
def places
    object.places.order("title")
end
```

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#associations

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted because you provided me with a better keyword : `order`. I was searching for `sort` and got absolutely no result, but with `order`, I got this SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972406/rails-render-as-json-include-nested-attribute-and-sort) which explains other methods to do what i wanted to - yours works like a charm too.

Comment: Quick note, if your child object also goes through a serialiser this will break that, and revert to using as_json

Comment: Weird that it doesn't have the same DSL as model associations, where you can just put the order there.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without adding an N+1 query?

Comment: I added this to the model's `has_many`: `has_many :images, ->{ order(position: :asc) }, class_name: "PropertyImage"`

Comment: Is there a way to sort by `:name`?

Answer (score 4):

I prefer this way

```rb
has_many :person_medals do
  object.places.order(:title)
end
```

Comment: This is nice. Cleaner and also addresses the issue commented by @FearMediocrity on the accepted answer - if the child object also goes through a serializer, your order will still stick.